# background-position technique for 'single-sprite-background-images'

Tags: css, background, background-image

What is a good 'image spriting' tool to turn single images into one big sprite with different background-position?

I know about http://spriteme.org/ but it doesn't seem to produce a result as nice as:

[goDaddy's](https://img5.wsimg.com/pc/img/1/77635_hf_sprite.png) or [Behance's](http://assets.behance.net/img/network/site/sprite.png?cb=95081662)

I've been doing it by hand for small hovers and icons but doing the entire website would take a while to hand-code all the background-position properties.

Thanks

Comment: wow, thats pretty amazing. thx for sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [SASS/COMPASS](http://compass-style.org/). Even if you are only using the [sprite functionality (called sprite mixin)](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) it is worth using it. There are some nice tutorials like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tl6bceyTjFw).